# How to find the data corresponding to the last date for every category in rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am currently trying to list different assets on a rails application. I want to access the name, and last values of each asset, all of that ordered by marketcap.

here is my database structure

```
`create_table "asset_values", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "date"
    t.integer "asset_id"
    t.float "price"
    t.float "marketcap"
    t.float "volume"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "assets", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "symbol"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end`
```

date is in unix time

Here is my model structure corresponding to asset

```
    has_many :asset_value
    validates :name, :symbol, uniqueness: true
    validates :name, :symbol,  presence: true
```

and here is my model structure corresponding to asset_values

```
     belongs_to :asset, foreign_key: "asset_id"
```

EXAMPLE:

```
Assets:
    id: 1, name: Bitcoin, symbol: BTC
    id: 2, name: Ethereum, symbol: ETH

Asset_values:
    id:1, price: 12000, marketcap: 211 000 000 000, volume 100, asset_id: 1, date: 1 598 300 000
    id:2, price: 11000, marketcap: 210 000 000 000, volume 110, asset_id: 1, date: 1 598 200 000
    id:3, price: 400, marketcap: 42 000 000 000, volume 20, asset_id: 2, date: 1 598 300 000
    id:4, price: 420, marketcap: 43 000 000 000, volume 20, asset_id: 2, date: 1 598 200 000


The_table_i_want : 
    id: 1, name: Bitcoin, symbol: BTC, price: 12000, marketcap: 211 000 000 000, volume 100, date: 1 598 300 000
    id: 2, name: Ethereum, symbol: ETH, price: 400, marketcap: 42 000 000 000, volume 20, date: 1 598 300 000
```

I tried different calls in order to access the data but none of them is working...
here is what i think is best

```
    sql = ("
      SELECT a.id, a.name, a.symbol, v.price, v.marketcap, v.volume, v.date
      FROM assets AS a
      INNER JOIN asset_values AS v ON a.id = v.asset_id
      INNER JOIN (
        SELECT MAX(date)
        FROM asset_values
        GROUP BY asset_id
        ) AS p 
      ON a.id = p.asset_id
      ORDER BY v.marketcap DESC
        ")
   @data = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

I am using postgresql and rails 6

Comment: I think it would be better to save the latest value marketcap inside assets table that way you can do very simple query. 

```Asset.order('marketcap desc')```

Comment: yes that would work but i prefer to have a clean database with no repetition ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if these adjustments to your query produce the results you would expect

```
  SELECT a.id
        ,a.name
        ,a.symbol
        ,v.price
        ,v.marketcap
        ,v.volume
        ,v.date
  FROM assets AS a
  INNER JOIN asset_values AS v 
        ON a.id = v.asset_id
  INNER JOIN (
        SELECT asset_id
              ,MAX(date) as max_date
        FROM asset_values
        GROUP BY asset_id
        ) AS p  
        ON v.asset_id = p.asset_id 
           AND v.date = p.max_date
  ORDER BY v.marketcap DESC
```

If you are using postgresql 9.3+ you can use lateral join

```
 SELECT a.id
        ,a.name
        ,a.symbol
        ,v.price
        ,v.marketcap
        ,v.volume
        ,v.date
  FROM assets AS a
  INNER JOIN LATERAL
  ( SELECT asset_id 
        ,price
        ,marketcap
        ,volume
        ,date
    FROM asset_values 
    WHERE asset_id=a.id
    ORDER BY created_at ASC LIMIT 1 ) v 
          ON v.asset_id=a.id
 ORDER BY v.marketcap DESC
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! However, I have a problem with the second. (ERROR: syntax error at or near "ORDER" LINE 18: ORDER BY v.marketcap DESC ^). I will use the first one

Comment: like any join it needs an on clause, which i forgot to write, I have edited my answer.